# how to: bind unbeforeunload call to window if function(param) is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

a flash movie where users can draw is calling a JS Function. Whenever something is changed in the movie calls `listenToUnload(true)`. Whenever the save button in the Flashmovie is pressed `listenToUnload(false);` is called.

```
function listenToUnload(saved) {

   if (saved) {

      $(window).bind('unload', function() {
          closeWindowWarning;
      });

   } else if (!saved) {
       $(window).unbind('unload');
   }

}

function closeWindowWarning() { return "You haven't saved your last changes"; }
```

So, I actually wonder if this is the correct way to do this?
Because `listenToUnload(true)` could be called multiple times in a row and I don't want to have the unload function bound multiple times to the window.

Is this the correct way of doing this? Any other approaches?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to bind on `beforeunload`, not `unload`.

You can store the flag (whether to confirm before unload) in a variable, or in `$(document).data('confirm_unload', TRUE_OR_FALSE)` and then:

```
function closeWindowWarning() { 
    if ($(document).data('confirm_unload'))
        return "You haven't saved your last changes"; 
}
```

And of course bind the beforeunload event once:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', closeWindowWarning)
```

You don't need to wrap `closeWindowWarning` in another function.

Comment: but how is this variable sent/set from within flash?

Comment: `function listenToUnload(flag) { $(document).data('confirm_unload', flag); }`

Comment: I absolutely don't get it. Could you please provide a little bit more detail. I can't call $(document).data from within Actionscript!

Comment: define the function `listenToUnload` as in my previous comment. You said that Actionscript alreay calls this function, right?